# Is there a way of keeping width and height of the div fixed when added padding?

Tags: html, css

For example:

```
.large{
    font-size: 200%;
}
.bluebox{
    background-color: blue;
    height: 200px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="bluebox">
    <p class="large">This is a bigger paragraph</p>
</div>
```

I want to keep div in fixed widht and height when I add padding to the content. (Yes I can pre-calculate padding and then give proper width but if there is a simpler way?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`box-sizing: border-box;` is what you're looking for.

It changes the default CSS box model to calculate widths and heights of elements including borders and padding but not margin.

> **[6.1. ‘box-sizing’ property](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-ui/#box-sizing)**
>
> **border-box**
>   The specified width and height (and respective min/max properties) on
>   this element determine the border box of the element. That is, any
>   padding or border specified on the element is laid out and drawn
>   inside this specified width and height.

**[EXAMPLE HERE](http://jsbin.com/jukax/1/edit)**

Answer (score 3):

The following CSS should work

```
box-sizing: border-box; 
padding:12px;
```